# Failed to clone iCheck Box

Tags: jquery, icheck

Havin list of checkbocksees using iCheck plugin.

```
<li>
   <input id="unique_id" name="request[accounts][0][advantages][swops]" type="checkbox" value="1" tabindex="34">
   <label for="unique_id">Some Text</label>
</li>
```

And in jQuery File is following script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
    });
});
```

When page load it becames like this:

```
<li>
    <div class="icheckbox_square-green" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
        <input id="unique_id" name="request[accounts][0][advantages][swops]" type="checkbox" value="1" tabindex="34" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
    </div>
    <label for="unique_id" class="">Swops</label>
</li>
```

And when i do clone

```
var add_id = 1;
$('.js-clone-account').click(function() {
var $new_form_block = $('.field_set_class').clone().prop('class', 'reply'+add_id);

$new_form_block.clearMyForm(); // Clears all input values

$new_form_block.find('#unique_id').prop('id', 'unique_id'+add_id).prop('name', 'old_name'+add_id);
$new_form_block.find('#unique_id'+add_id).next().prop('for', 'unique_id'+add_id);

$new_form_block.appendTo("#other_div");
            add_id = add_id + 1;
        });
```

**Problem**
OnClick is clonning all elements but checkboxes doesn't work anymor. And id for label isn't added by one this is because `div` tag and `ins` tag where added. On simple checkboxes `.clone` work. Any idea would be very helpfull.

Comment: Noted by the developer of icheck at https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/issues/214

Answer (score 0):

Use this way where your cloning:

```
$('#div_to_clone').find('.checkbox_container').html( < input type='checkbox' 
    class='checkbox_class' name='chechbox_name'  value='1' > );<br>
$('.contrainer .checkbox_class').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
    increaseArea: '20%'
});
```

And where you trigger `ifChecked` use this type of syntax for calling it:

```
$('#container_id').on('ifChecked','.checkbox_class', function (event){  

});
```